# Canvas image perspective

Tags: image, html5-canvas

I have started using canvas and working with images.

I want to achieve something like this - an image with perspective.

[image]
!

I tried with the `ctx.transform(1,0.5,-0.5,1,30,10)` method but is not exactly perspective and i can't not find a good tutorial.

Can somebody link me a tutorial or help in general?

Answer (score 4):

This is an easy approach I just did...
Check it [**here**](http://jsbin.com/opukaw/10/edit).

The technique  is pretty simple. You just divide the image in a lot of pieces, this case you make many vertical splits. Then you resize every piece and make them have descending height.

That gives you some kind of sense of perspective.

The way to use that function is the next:

```
drawPerspective(canvasID, imgURL, scale); // for the scale value try something between 0.5 and 1
```

Comment: I need to have more control with the angles and edges. I need to have different perspectives to simulate a 3d environment...

Comment: Now I added a widthScale which is a number which gives you more control over the angles.

Comment: With that technique you can scale both axes (the horizonal axis and the vertical axis). This example only scales the horizontal axis, but you can modify it a litle bit and make it for the vertical axis too.

Comment: By the way, if you want quite more advanced 3d features, you could check [WebGL](http://www.webgl.com/) which is an open-source graphic library based on HTML5 Canvas and Javascript

Comment: A made a simple demo for you... ["3D" picture animation](http://jsbin.com/opukaw/17/edit)